# issue with onClickListner with LableField blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I am developing one app in which i need to `call at particular phone number` for that i have take `LableField` and make `Number.setChangeListener(this);` and implement its method `fieldChanged` and try to handle event but i cant able to do it with this `lablefield`

**Here is code ::**

```
import net.rim.blackberry.api.invoke.Invoke;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.invoke.PhoneArguments;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FontFamily;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.BitmapField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.NullField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.BackgroundFactory;

public class AboutM1 extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener {

    VerticalFieldManager TOPVFM , DescriptionVFM,BottomVFM;
    HorizontalFieldManager TOPHFM,CallHFM,EmailHFM,VIsitUsHFM ;

    LabelField toplable,Description,Description2,Number,callus,Email,EmailID,Visitus,VisitLink;

    Bitmap logom1;
    BitmapField imgField;

    public AboutM1() {

        ((VerticalFieldManager) getMainManager())
                .setBackground(BackgroundFactory
                        .createSolidBackground(0xEDEDED));

         TOPVFM = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
         TOPHFM = new HorizontalFieldManager(
                FIELD_HCENTER | FIELD_VCENTER);


         AllBITMAPDeclaration();

         toplable = new LabelField("\n Welcome to", FIELD_BOTTOM) {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.setBackgroundColor(0xECECEC);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                g.setColor(Color.RED);

                g.clear();
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };

        FontFamily fontFamily[] = FontFamily.getFontFamilies();
        Font font = fontFamily[1].getFont(FontFamily.CBTF_FONT, 20);
        font = fontFamily[1].getFont(Font.BOLD, 25);
        toplable.setFont(font);


         imgField = new BitmapField(logom1, FIELD_BOTTOM);

        TOPHFM.add(toplable);
        TOPHFM.add(imgField);

        TOPVFM.add(TOPHFM);


        add(TOPVFM);
        LabelField Greenline = new LabelField(
                "_______________________________________") {
            protected void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor(0x324F85);
                super.paint(g);
            }

        };

        add(Greenline);

         DescriptionVFM = new VerticalFieldManager(
                VERTICAL_SCROLL);
         Description = new LabelField(
                "\nasdasdasd  as da sd asd a sd reert er ter t e",
                USE_ALL_WIDTH);
         Description2 = new LabelField(
                "\n\n About Us \n For customer care \n\n");
        /*
         * add(Description); add(Description2);
         */

        DescriptionVFM.add(Description);
        DescriptionVFM.add(new NullField(NullField.FOCUSABLE));
        DescriptionVFM.add(Description2);


        /******************************Bottom Area******************************************/

         BottomVFM = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH );
            CallHFM = new HorizontalFieldManager(
                FIELD_VCENTER);
             callus = new LabelField("Call: ", FIELD_VCENTER);
            Number = new LabelField("+91-79-30487400", FIELD_VCENTER) {


            protected void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor(0x324F85);

                // g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, 50, 5, 7, 7);
                super.paint(g);
            }

            };
            font = fontFamily[2].getFont(Font.BOLD, 18);
            Number.setFont(font);

            CallHFM.add(callus);
            CallHFM.add(Number);
            Number.setChangeListener(this);

            EmailHFM = new  HorizontalFieldManager(FIELD_VCENTER);
             Email = new LabelField("Email: ", FIELD_VCENTER);
             EmailID = new LabelField("Customasdercare@m1asdshopping.com", FIELD_VCENTER) {
                protected void paint(Graphics g) {
                    g.setColor(0x324F85);
                    super.paint(g);
                    }
                };

                EmailID.setFont(font);
                EmailID.setChangeListener(this);
                EmailHFM.add(Email);
                EmailHFM.add(EmailID);

             VIsitUsHFM = new  HorizontalFieldManager(FIELD_VCENTER);
             Visitus = new LabelField("Visit us at: ", FIELD_VCENTER);
             VisitLink = new LabelField("www.asdasd.com", FIELD_VCENTER) {
                protected void paint(Graphics g) {
                    g.setColor(0x324F85);
                    super.paint(g);
                    }
                };

                VisitLink.setFont(font);
                VisitLink.setChangeListener(this);
                VIsitUsHFM.add(Visitus);
                VIsitUsHFM.add(VisitLink);


        BottomVFM.add(CallHFM);
        BottomVFM.add(EmailHFM);
        BottomVFM.add(VIsitUsHFM);

        // add(BottomVFM);
        DescriptionVFM.add(BottomVFM);


        /********************************* END BOTTOM ************************************************/
        add(DescriptionVFM);

    }

    private void AllBITMAPDeclaration() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logom1 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("logo36X36.png");
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(field == Number )
        {
            Dialog.alert("asdasd");
             /* PhoneArguments arguments = new PhoneArguments(PhoneArguments.ARG_CALL, "180065449877"); 
              Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE, arguments);*/
        }
        if(field == EmailID)
        {
            Dialog.alert("asdasd");
        }
        if(field == VisitLink)
        {
            Dialog.alert("asdasd");

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this -

```
        LabelField  Number = new LabelField("+91-79-30345487400a5675675676", FIELD_VCENTER|Field.FOCUSABLE) {
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(0x324F85);

            // g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, 50, 5, 7, 7);
            super.paint(g);
        }
        protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
           Dialog.alert("clicked");
            return super.navigationClick(status, time);
        }


        };
        add(Number);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the method `navigationClick` on your `LabelField`.

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
    fieldChangeNotify(0);
    return true;
}
```